# How to start writing a corda application from scratch?

Tags: corda

I am new to Corda and started working on 1 project. This will be a normal project. I want to know how should I start, how to create the project, what dependencies should I use and all. I know the details about the State/Contract and Flow. All I want to know is where to start from.

Please let e know your response.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the CorDapp templates:

- [Java](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java)
- [Kotlin](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin)

These show you how to set up your project using Gradle.

You can then extend the template by following the Hello, World! tutorial [here](https://docs.corda.net/hello-world-introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks Joel, Will start working on that now!! I'll post some more queries if I'm stuck in between. Thanks again

Comment: I have one more question on this one, how to add node specific state variable in Corda and how to initialize them. For example I want to set different Initial amount to each node while these are created, and then perform some actions on it based on flow. Is there anything that I can use as a reference.

Comment: I've answered your separate question :)